# How should I go about animating over 200 images in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, animation

I have over 200 images i want to animate over the space of around 10 seconds. I have tried using `animationImages` by loading the images into an array and then calling the `startAnimating` method. This worked okay in the simulator but crashed the iPad.

I have tried calling an `NStimer` every 1/25th of a second and changing the image each time the timer fired. This performed better than the previous method, it worked well in the simulator but also crashed near the end of the (laggy) animation on the iPad.

Can someone help me out and tell me the ideal way of approaching this problem? Thanks.

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
- (void) humptyFallingAnim {

    NSString *filename;
    if (humptyImageCounter < 285) {
        filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Humpty Animation HD1.2 png sequence/humpty_HD1.2_%d.png", humptyImageCounter];
            UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];
            humptyFalling.image = someImage;
            NSLog(@"loaded image: %d", humptyImageCounter);
        humptyImageCounter++;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Timer invalidated");
        [humptyTimer invalidate];
        humptyTimer = nil;
    }

}
```

EDIT: Some new code that isn't working for me

```
NSString *filename;
    if (humptyImageCounter < 285) {
        filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Humpty Animation HD1.2 png sequence/humpty_HD1.2_%d.png", humptyImageCounter];
        @autoreleasepool {
            UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filename];
            humptyFalling.image = someImage;
            NSLog(@"loaded image: %d", humptyImageCounter);
        }
        humptyImageCounter++;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Timer invalidated");
        [humptyTimer invalidate];
        humptyTimer = nil;
    }
```

EDIT 2:

```
-(void) motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"You shook it!");
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imgSnail];
    if (deviceHasBeenShaken == 0) {
        deviceHasBeenShaken = 1;
    }
    humptyTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1/25) target:self selector:@selector(humptyFallingAnim) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [self moveHumptyPosition];

}
```

Comment: Did you try loading images into `CALayer`s and then animating the layers?

Comment: 1) How big are the images? 2) Any reason not to make a video?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I haven't tried using `CALayer`s. I haven't used them before - could you direct to something that might suit this situation? Thanks

Comment: @sosborn 1) The retina images are around 100KB each. 2) I don't know, the animation is triggered by the device being shaken, i don't know if that makes a difference. I'd also be worried about losing out on image quality which is essential for this

Comment: Your device is very likely running out of memory. Image quality with video won't be a problem if you encode the video correctly. How the video is triggered does not matter.

Comment: Post above how you managed to do it previously.

Comment: @sosborn Would i be able to display the first frame of the video before the device is shook and then permanently display the final frame after the video has finished playing?

Comment: Sure - why not? Don't ever forget that you are the programmer and the device works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this sounds like a job for OpenGL ES. Is the app a game?

Answer (score 3):

Memory management :).

```
NSString* somePath;
UIImageView *imageView;
for (i=0;i<200;i++) {
@autoreleasepool {
UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:somePath];
imageView.image = someImage; //every time this line is executed, old reference disappears and previous UIImage is discarded
}
}
```

I mean, you have to implement autoreleasepools and don't use +(UIImage *) imageNamed: method, because it caches images.

**UPDATE**
Let me explain. Your problem is memory management related. Your app has to use device's memory efficiently but your actually doesn't. I don't know how your app works, but general idea is shown above. 
**UPDATE 2** let me know whether you use ARC or not.

**UPDATE 3** sorry for my bizarre language but it's late. Forgive me :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes i do use ARC.

Comment: When i try using this code i don't see my animation. This is my code: EDIT: i'll put it in my post above

Comment: I'll add in the trigger for some context - the image change is triggered every 1/25 second

Comment: how is it related ? I mean the first chunk of code with the second

Comment: Ah right, sorry. The first chunk of code is the `humptyFallingAnim` called in the `NSTimer`. I didn't realise i left that out

Comment: Here: imageWithContentsOfFile:somestring you have to set path to a photo :), not it's filename

Comment: So i gave it a go - it works better than the previous two methods but is still laggy. No crash though, which is positive! I think i'll try the `CALayer` approach below and then maybe the video

Answer (score 3):

Try using `CALayer` implicit animation. Create your layers and set their images in a loop, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *allLayers = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 200 ; i++) {
    CGImageRef image = ...; // Get i-th image from an image source
    CALayer* sub = [CALayer layer];
    sub.contents = (__bridge id)image;
    sub.contentsRect = CGRectMake(...); // Create a rectangle based on the image size
    [self.layer addSublayer:sub];
    [allLayers addObject:sub];
}
```

Now you can start animating your layers implicitly by setting their properties:

```
for (CALayer *sub in allLayers) {
    sub.position = CGMakePoint(...); // The position to which to move the image
}
```

Once you are done with the layers, remove them from superview:

```
for (CALayer *sub in allLayers) {
    [sub removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look at this now and get back to you

Comment: You say, "now you can start animating your layers by setting their properties". How exactly do i simply flick through them at 25fps?

Comment: @garethdn Oh, I though that by "animate" you meant to move the images around, turn them, etc. If you need to flip through lots of images quickly, you may be better off combining them in an *atlas*, and doing the sprite animation the way it is described in [this excellent article](http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/).

Comment: Ok, i;ll take a look but think i have to sleep now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) my friend. Save yourself the headache. What you are talking about is a hundred times more efficiently done with OpenGLES. However, OpenGL is unnecessary complicated, and cocos2d provides a good abstraction layer over it so that you can just do it with a few lines of code.